# Google: Where, in my google account, is the meta tag to verify my domain?

Tags: google, site-verification

I have a Google APPS account which uses my domain, like `support@my-business-domain.com`. I was working fine but yesterday I just launch my new website at: `www.my-business-domain.com` and delete the old one. Thing is that in the old one was the meta tag to verify my domain with the Google service.

I need to re-create this metatag but I can't find it in the Google panel. 
Should I do this using Google Webmaster?

**Update**: I try to enter in Google Webmaster Tools, but the access is restricted to me. The message says "Please contact the domain administrator". Thing is that I am the "domain administrator". What am I missing here?

Comment: Deleting the metatag wouldn't stop you logging into Webmaster Tools. Sounds like you need to contact them, if you have multiple Google accounts, login to the other account and visit web masters tools and double check.

Comment: Is there a possibility that someone else owns your domain without the www. prepended to it? By default, trying to access www.example.com and example.com could produce very different results.

Comment: @SimonHayter when I try to loggin into Webmaster, it says: "You can't access the Webmaster Tool. Login into the Console and enable Webmaster Tools". Then I login into the Console, but I don't know how to enable it.

Comment: @SimonHayter If I try to load http://www.google.com/a/mydomain.com I am redirected to the Console: https://admin.google.com/AdminHome

Comment: @SimonHayter If in the Console I go into Domains I can see the Main Domain but I see no setting or anything like that to allow to re-verify my domain.